# Retrieve the content of meta description from web-page using selenium webdriver

Tags: java, selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

Want to get the  content of  meta description of page using webdriver.

Let say , from below DOM want to retrieve text 
`Test.com provides a complete software solution for creating online tests and managing enterprise and specialist certification programs, in up to 22 languages`

```
<script src="content/js/jquery.min.js">
<meta content="Test.com provides a complete software solution for creating online tests and managing enterprise and specialist certification programs, in up to 22 languages." name="description">
<meta content="Test.com" name="keywords">
```

I tried with

```
System.out.println(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//meta[@name='description']")).getText());
```

But above code not worked for me.

Answer (score 16):

You're trying to get an attribute value, so instead of `getText()` use `getAttribute()` :

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//meta[@name='description']"))
      .getAttribute("content")
```

Answer (score 0):

you could also try for

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@name='description']"))
      .getAttribute("content")
```